# How can I convert updateMany with ArrayFilters options mongodb query into Golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

I am facing issue to write golang code for mongodb query. I had tried to convert following mongodb query:

```
db.batches.updateMany(
         {"batchedOrders.newOrderObject.orderDetails.trackingId" :  "ORDER_JEET_2023_02_05_01"},
         { $set: { "batchedOrders.$[elem].newOrderObject.pickupDetails.note" : "Welcome" } },
         { arrayFilters: [ { "elem.newOrderObject.orderDetails.trackingId": "ORDER_JEET_2023_02_05_01" } ] }
      )
```

Golang code:

Here b is interface{} and carrying following data:

```
{
    "batchedOrders.$[elem].newOrderObject.dropoffDetails.recipientDetails.email": "das@rara.delivery",
    "batchedOrders.$[elem].newOrderObject.orderDetails.dimensions.height": 0,
    "batchedOrders.$[elem].newOrderObject.orderDetails.dimensions.length": 0,
    "batchedOrders.$[elem].newOrderObject.orderDetails.dimensions.unit": "cm",
    "batchedOrders.$[elem].newOrderObject.orderDetails.dimensions.width": 0,
    "batchedOrders.$[elem].newOrderObject.orderDetails.orderDeliveryDetails.sla.dropoff": 1675712794,
    "batchedOrders.$[elem].newOrderObject.orderDetails.parcelSize": "Medium",
    "batchedOrders.$[elem].newOrderObject.orderDetails.weightDetails.billableWeight": 5,
    "batchedOrders.$[elem].newOrderObject.orderDetails.weightDetails.volWeight": 5,
    "batchedOrders.$[elem].newOrderObject.orderDetails.weightDetails.weight": 5,
    "batchedOrders.$[elem].newOrderObject.orderDetails.weightIndex": 1,
    "batchedOrders.$[elem].newOrderObject.pickupDetails.pickupIncharge.name": "Mukesh"
}
```

Following is the golang code:

```
data, _ := bson.Marshal(b)

    err = bson.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &doc)

    arrayFilters := options.ArrayFilters{Filters: []interface{}{bson.D{
        {Key: "elem.newOrderObject.orderDetails.trackingId", Value: trackingId},
    }}}

    opts := options.UpdateOptions{
        ArrayFilters: &arrayFilters,
    }

    res, err := db.Collection(BATCH_COLLECTION_NAME).UpdateMany(ctx, bson.D{{Key: "batchedOrders.newOrderObject.orderDetails.trackingId", Value: trackingId}}, bson.M{"$set": doc}, &opts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(lg.Info(err))
        return false, err
    }
```

I am getting following error:

```
WriteString can only write while positioned on a Element or Value but is positioned on a TopLevel
```

I am trying to update multiple data in mongodb database. But getting error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to successfully use the `UpdateMany` method, you should do something similar to this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

var (
    ctx    context.Context
    cancel context.CancelFunc
)

type Message struct {
    ID   string `json:"id" bson:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    // set MongoDB connection
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017")
    mongoClient, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer mongoClient.Disconnect(ctx)

    // select collection
    collection := mongoClient.Database("demodb").Collection("myCollection")
    defer collection.Drop(ctx)

    fmt.Println("original documents")
    // insert some random msg
    if _, err := collection.InsertMany(ctx, []interface{}{
        Message{"1", "John Doe"},
        Message{"2", "Suzy Lee"},
        Message{"3", "John Doe"},
    }); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // get records
    var messagesTmp []bson.M
    cursorTmp, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := cursorTmp.All(ctx, &messagesTmp); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, v := range messagesTmp {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
    fmt.Println(strings.Repeat("#", 100))

    // update
    var updateRes *mongo.UpdateResult
    if updateRes, err = collection.UpdateMany(ctx,
        bson.M{"name": "John Doe"},
        bson.D{
            bson.E{
                Key: "$set",
                Value: bson.D{
                    bson.E{
                        Key:   "name",
                        Value: "John Doe - Edited",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    ); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("num docs updated:", updateRes.ModifiedCount)

    // list all
    fmt.Println(strings.Repeat("#", 100))
    fmt.Println("new documents")
    var messages []Message
    cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := cursor.All(ctx, &messages); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, v := range messages {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

Here, the relevant part is the `// update` section. First, we build the filter criteria we're going to use to fetch the documents to update. Then, we specify to `$set` a field `name` to a particular value `John Doe - Edited`.

The rest of the code is used to build a trivial program to demonstrate that the actual change is working. Feel free to adapt my example code to your specs and let me know if works for you too!